# How to get a Column from another table to a new table in same database as auto generate Column?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the username or id from users table in MySql to another table in the same database when I uploading a picture from the system to the database. How can I automate this function?

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `image` longtext NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `id` INT FK
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the images table that I want to upload the image and the username is from the Users table and id is userid from the same table. When I logged into the system as a user then I want to upload a picture. So when I am uploading the picture I want to get the logged username and userid to record in the images table as an automated column.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your create table query. Why do you want to keep `username` in `images` table while you already have userid which is enough to be foreign key to users table ?

Comment: `Id int fk` eh?